# Freeing a non-allocated pointer

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

The following code throws the error:

mem(44582) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9f8a4000e0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

I'm not sure what's going on. I'm freeing an area of memory that I explicitly malloc'd, does it have something to do with passing in a pointer to another method?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE 10

void readstringbuffered(char *buffer);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(BUFFERSIZE);
    readstringbuffered(buffer);                                               
    printf("%s",buffer);
    free(buffer);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void readstringbuffered(char *buffer) 
{
    FILE *source;
    source = fopen("hello.txt","r");
    int current_size = BUFFERSIZE;
    int len = 0;
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
    {
        if(len == current_size-1)
        {
            current_size *= 2;
            char *temp = (char *)realloc(buffer,current_size);
            if(!temp)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"out of memory");
                exit(1);
            }
            buffer = temp;
        }
        buffer[len] = c;
        len++;
    }
    buffer[len] = 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return values of `malloc` or `realloc` in a  C program.

Comment: This question is a duplicate many many times over.

Comment: Does `"hello.txt"` actually exist?

Comment: Also, using `malloc(BUFFERSIZE)` doesn't get you 10 `char*`, but this will `char *buffer = malloc( BUFFERSIZE * sizeof(char*));`. When I did that your code runs fine, even with the `free()` command...unless your're *trying* to invoke that out-of-memory section in your while-loop?

Answer (score 8):

C is a pass by value language.  The modifications you make to `buffer` inside your `readstringbuffered()` function have no effect on the value of `buffer` in `main()`.  If the `realloc()` there is ever executed, you've already freed the `buffer` that `main` knows about, and when you return - BAM - double free.

A possible solution is to pass a pointer to `buffer`, rather than `buffer` itself.  Change the signature of `readstringbuffered()` to be:

```
void readstringbuffered(char **buffer)
```

And then use `*buffer` inside it.  At the call site, you'd use `readstringbuffered(&buffer)` to pass the necessary pointer.

Comment: how then can the problem be fixed?

Comment: @nope Pass a `char**` and call the function as `readstringbuffered(&buffer)`, then set `*buffer = temp`, and any other modifications to correct for receiving a `**` instead of just a `*`

Answer (score 3):

realloc() can release the previously allocated memory and allocate it again somewhere else, which makes your buffer pointer in main totally invalid. You can pass buffer by reference and have readstringbuffered() modify it accordingly, or return a pointer to buffer instead of void.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer pointer in `main()` will not be modified according to the reallocations you do in `readstringbuffered()`, you may write back the buffer pointer using a pointer to the buffer pointer (`pBuffer`), like this:

```
void readstringbuffered(char** pBuffer,size_t* pSize) 
{
    char* buffer = *pBuffer;
    size_t size = MIN_SIZE;
    char* newBufferPtr = (char*) realloc(buffer,size);
    if(newBufferPtr)
    {
        buffer = newBufferPtr;            
    }
    else
    {
        //out of memory
        free(buffer);
        buffer = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    if(buffer)
    {
        //fill the buffer
    }

    //must always execute
    *pBuffer = buffer;
    *pSize = size;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* buffer = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    readstringbuffered(&buffer,&size);
    if(buffer)
    {
        printf("%s",buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        //error
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```